# Streamreader read file on same directory

Tags: c#

I want to read a `CSV` file which is located at the same directory as my code.

[image: files]

I want to read the content of the `.csv`

```
    public static void InitializeItems()
    {
        itemList = new Dictionary<int, Item>();

        string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\Items.csv");

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            int lineCounter = 0; // Do I really need such a counter for the current line?

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                string name = values[0];

                itemList.Add(lineCounter, new Item(name));

                lineCounter++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, Item> itemList;
```

By doing so I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` exception. The file `C:\Items.csv` does not exist.

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns me the path to the `.exe` file.

What is wrong with the path?

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns me the path to the .exe file` You sure about that?  Maybe you should be using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: Any of these will work, `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`
`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
`System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`
`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`
`Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: By some chance, did you forget to make file **copy to output directory when newer** in Visual Studio? Otherwise, this file won't be present in output directory (where executable file is), it will only be in your project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current directory is *not necessary* the directory where exe has been executed:

```
 // Current directory can be whatever you want: 
 Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"c:\SomeDirectory";
```

If you are looking for the *exe* path you can try

```
 string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

In your case:

```
 using System.Reflection;

 ...

 string filePath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), 
   "Items.csv");
```

**Edit:** You can simplify the code (get rid of `StreamReader`) with a help of *Linq*:

```
    var itemList = File
      .ReadLines(filePath)        
      .Select((line, index) => new {
         value = new Item(line.SubString(0, line.IndexOf(',') + 1)),
         index = index
       })
      .ToDictionary(item => item.index, item => item.value);
```

Comment: so I have to put the file into the debug folder? Your code leads me to this folder, I can't read the file while debugging

Comment: you can see the problem here https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/473901040140288000/491180526623916032/unknown.png

Comment: @MHComputech: where exactly do you want to place `Items.csv`? In the exe folder (i.e. where executing file is)? If it is yes, then it's `...\Debug` folder, if not, please, specify the location

Comment: hm well I think I'll place it to the Debug folder then. Because I don't really know it yet

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the path of the .exe file like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Then, you must put `BuildAction` as `Content`. With this, the file is copied to the folder exe after build.

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "file.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, `what is wrong`: You can not have your file starting with a backslash when using `Path.Combine`. You should write it as this:

```
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Items.csv");
```

**Edit**:
By default the 'CurrentDirectory' points to your exe file, unless you change it in code or in a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

First it is advisable to create a new folder in your project to store files and name it `MyFiles`, 
then lets say your file is a `csv`file and named `test.csv` 
so this can be accessed  like this :

```
string testFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"MyFiles\test.csv");
```